# Can anyone explain the below code How it works?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have a custom class that has overridden `hashcode()` and `equals()` method

```
class Employee1 {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Employee1(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee1 other = (Employee1) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and in main class I am using a `Map` having `Object` as `Key`

```
Map<Integer,Employee1> g = new HashMap<>();
    Employee1 e = new Employee1(1);
    Employee1 e1 = new Employee1(2);
    g.put(1, e);
    g.put(2, e1);
    Employee1 e4 = g.get(1);
    e4.setId(3);
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Employee1> e3:g.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(e3.getKey()+" "+e3.getValue().getId());
    }
```

My question is how come the key of the map is changed even though I have overridden `hashcode` and `equals` methods,key should be same but I am able to get and set the id and its  reflecting in the `map`

The output for above code is

1 3
2 2

Comment: What does the key of a map entry have to do with a property in the value object? And what does any of it have to do with `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations in the value object? Answer: nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Methods `equals()` and `hashCode()` are used for keys in a `HashMap` not for values. To see  the difference you can try to use your class `Employee1` as a value in a `Map` or just to use `HashSet<Employee1>`, it uses `HashMap` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

*"how come the key of the map is changed"* - **it does not change**, as you can see the 1 and 2 in the output which are what you originally used in the `put`.

What you can change are the contents of what the object inside the map points to, the value. The map does not copy the `Employee1` when you put it into the map, it retains a reference to the same instance which you know as `e`. If you get that value from the map `e4` now is the exact same thing as `e`.

[Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) may be helpful to you.

What you should **never** do is to mutate something that is involved in the `hashCode` computation (if there is a chance somebody actually relies on the hashcode). Because after the change the hashcode of the object changes, the HashMap (or HashSet) does not see the change since it does not recompute the hashcode since there is no way for it to know you mutated something (relevant).

Comment: If I make object as key then also its changing its value


Map<Employee1,Integer> g = new HashMap<>();
        Employee1 e = new Employee1(1);
        Employee1 e1 = new Employee1(2);
        g.put(e,1);
        g.put(e1,2);
        e.setId(3);
        for(Map.Entry<Employee1,Integer> e3:g.entrySet()) {
           System.out.println(e3.getKey().getId()+"***************"+e3.getValue());
        }

again the output is 3 1 2 2

Comment: @RamSomani read the answer again and read through the link I posted.